# Dropping Rows with a does not equal condition

Tags: pandas

I'm attempting to create a new dataframe that drops a certain segment of records from an existing dataframe.

```
df2=df[df['AgeSeg']!='0-1']
```

when I look at df2, the records with '0-1' Age Segment are still there.

[Output with 0-1 records still in it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ML8lW.png)

I would expect the new dataframe to not have them.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output, that way is easier to help you

Comment: What is the output of `df.AgeSeg.unique()`? Do you need to strip some whitespace?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isin` (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)

Simple example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3, 2, 9], 'col2': [4, 5, 6, 3, 0]})

df = df[df['col1'].isin([2]) != True]
```

df before:

```
   col1  col2
0     1     4
1     2     5
2     3     6
3     2     3
4     9     0
```

df after:

```
   col1  col2
0     1     4
2     3     6
4     9     0
```

Comment: Did not work.  not sure what about the 0-1 that it is impeding things to work.

Comment: `df = df[df['col1'].isin([0, 1]) != True]` ? or `df = df[df['col1'].isin(['0-1']) != True]`  like string?

Comment: Your link was helpful.  I used the following to correct the problem:  df2=df[df['AgeSeg'].str.contains('0-1') != True]